# How would Aliens care for "endangered" humans?

Tags: science-fiction, humans, aliens, environment

Sci-fi novel. Book is told from the POV of a alien that works at the sanctuary.

I don't think this is too important, but the aliens are sort of an anthro-snail that lives on the underground and hates sunlight because it burns their skin thing, with no eyes, but with a real good heat vision. SO GOOD they would be able to look a leaf and see all its veins, just no color.

So. A while ago, a planet with a Intergalactic PETA of sorts, included humans on their "this species is evolving towards intelligence so must be protected list" (they do not know all the garbage in the ocean, forest clearances, etc., are our fault. They don't think humans are smart enough to do those things, and  think a sort of Ophiocordyceps unilateralis took over most humans, that's why they are doing the things they are doing, and will end extincting themselves by ACCIDENT rather than their own wrong doing. That's why they wanna save us). So, aliens spaceships began patrolling earth. Now, about 120ish years since the start of the project, humans got used to aliens ships hanging around, and even tried interaction with them. Since the aliens don't consider 21th century society rational yet, due to them being ULTRA developed, almost like galactic gods, they interact with people same way we humans would interact with tigers, lions, hippos or other sort of wild animal like that.

So. to protect the species from the "fungus" , they write down the humans that have no kids (since those would be infected, like the parents, since the fungus seems to be invisible to the naked eye, so are its spores), are fully grown adults, and don't seem to be doing so well here on earth,  and takes them to a "wildlife" sanctuary in their home planet. The place is tailored to fit earth's life needs, and it works sort of like a  safari zoo. Other aliens can go there for entertainment and etc. to see the humans that seem to be "free" from the fungus, but are never returning earth by whatever. some humans with the "fungus" will  captured, "treated", "rehabilitated" and sent back to Earth, so these are kept in a different part of the sanctuary.

According to laws, they are NOT allowed to breed humans, so all the ones staying on the sanctuary are sterilized.

But...How would they care SO INTENSELY for people and don't figure that they are actually rational? Like. Their sanctuaries are a good place to be, (since they don't people escaping and causing chaos on their planet), so I bet they would have books, paints, paper, seeds to plant, things to see, do, build, etc. (internet?) So. They feed humans, take care of them, even have been studying their life on earth for 120 years. How come they haven't figured humans, although don't have the same technology, are as rational as them (but do a lot of dumb things..) ? They think of people as "inventive bees with what seems to be a rudimentary form of written language, but nothing that seems to convey a message yet". I'm also not too sure how the sanctuary would work, like, they sure would see humans doing very rational things, like showing drawings to the aliens to specify what they want to eat or things like that. (the aliens paint allow them see what's print with their heat vision)

Is it possible that the aliens would think humans are just a "mimic" of them and don't pay too much attention to their actions?

Comment: This question seems to be rather out of focus. First of all, I'm not certain which meaning of "care" you intend. At first, you seem to mean "look after" or "tend". But since you've got the whole zoo / nature reserve thing under control, that doesn't seem to be the issue. Later, you stress "care SO INTENSELY for", that I really wonder if the meaning you're intending conveys a more emotional context, the way friends care for one another. That kind of makes sense in the context of them being oblivious to human behaviour. Also, you're asking several independent questions. You also ask...

Comment: ...why they can't figure humans out. This is a separate question and ought to be treated as such. The third question, the one about whether humans are mimics, is one of alien preconeptualisation and perspective. That's neither here nor there. You've got an interesting foundation here, but I'm going to vote to close your question until you can do some edit work. Please do check our [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how to compose & write a question! Try to improve your overall coherence and try not to write in stream of consciousness style.

Answer (score 1):

After the European colonization of the Americas started, it took a formal document written by the Pope to recognize that the indigenous populations were actually humans bearing a soul, and not some sort of beasts.

The movie Planet of the Apes follows the same trope: the apes think humans are just imitating what they observe, not being originally creative/intelligent.

It might very well be an anthropocentric misconception, but it can also be a more universal one, that one intelligent species tends to see intelligence only in itself as a sort of "blessing from the higher ups".

Therefore it's definitely possible that the aliens would overlook the behavior of the humans and not see it as intelligent.